# Effective bundle splitting with webpack 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to implement an effective strategy for bundle splitting with webpack 4 in an app that I am developing.

The app has a lot of npm dependencies (React, redux, etc) and it has    code splitting for routes, one of the routes is loaded asynchronously    and is the only one that depends on a specific **npm module** and the other one is the main file, when I build the application with the following configuration:

```
splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: 'vendors',
},
```

I get three files

- main.js
- vendor.js
- 0.chunk.js

**0 is the code for the route**

The bad thing about this is that the file vendor.js has the npm dependency that is only needed by the 0.chunk.js, I think this is inefficient.

What can I do to specify that that npm module should be added to the 0.chunk.js file instead of putting it inside the vendor file?